# Including INAppStoreWindow in existing project

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

How can I include [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) into my existing xcode project?
When I simply include this:

```
#import "INAppStoreWindow.h"
```

I will get a error, that it is not existing. I read that I have to compile with linker flag

```
-fobjc-arc
```

But, I don't know how to get that working.
Can someone please help me?
For any questions, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

you need to set compiler flags to -fno-objc-arc for INAppStoreWindow.m file. To Set this go to Target->Build Phases->Compile Sources->INAppStoreWindow.m  and set the compiler flags to -fno-objc-arc.

Answer (score 0):

To set A linker flag you should go to your project file
Target->Build Phases->Compile Sources->INAppStoreWindow.m
(See image Below)

[image]

Double click the INAppStoreWindow.m file
and add the `-fno-objc-arc.` flag to it.
(See image below)

[image]